# IdentityServer Login with external provider not working for long login_hint or acr_values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, identityserver3

In my `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` I set the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications` **RedirectToIdentityProvider**

It looks like this:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
{
    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
    {
        n.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = "LoginHint";
        n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "idp:CustomIdProvider";
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

In this example I am able to receive the LoginHint and everything works fine.

Now if I set the `LoginHint` to something that is about 1000 characters long
(The same happens for `AcrValues`), the IdentityServer shows an error message:

> There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again.

and the **logs** show this message:

> No cookie matching signin id found

This only happens when the `LoginHint` (or `AcrValues`) reach a certain size

It seems there is a problem when storing the cookies or reading the cookies 
maybe they are to big

## What I've already tried/configured:

**Web Config** for both, client and server ([according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853785/6754146) all these values should be high enough, I will reduce them to appropriate values when it's working):

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxUrlLength="109990" maxQueryStringLength="100000" maxRequestLength="256000" />
</system.web>
<!--...-->
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="100000" maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
</requestFiltering>
```

**InputLengthRestrictions** in the `IdentityServerOptions`(again the values should be sufficient):

```
InputLengthRestrictions = new InputLengthRestrictions
{
    UserName = 51200,
    AcrValues = 51200,
    LoginHint = 51200
}
```

<sub>This is a follow up question for this one: [Send a custom parameter to an external identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49813456/6754146)</sub>

**EDIT:**

## More information about my structure:

My client receives a token as queryparameter which can be very long(about 900 chars).
The client now redirects to the IdentityServer using following options for: `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);`

**Clients Startup.cs:**

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
{
    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
    {
        var token = n.Request.Query.Get("token");
        if (token != null)
        {
            n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("token", token);
            n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "idp:CustomIdP";
        }

    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

The rest of the `options` is pretty basic

On my IdentityServer I configure the `AuthenticationOptions`' `IdentityProviders`-Property as you can see in this excerpt of my IdServer Configuration and I also set the `InputLengthRestrictions` to a high value, just to be safe:

**IdentityServer Startup.cs:**

```
IdentityServerOptions options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    InputLengthRestrictions = new InputLengthRestrictions
    {
        RedirectUri = 51200,
        AcrValues = 51200,
        LoginHint = 51200
    },
    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions {

        CookieOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.CookieOptions
        {
            SessionStoreProvider = new SessionStoreProvider()
        },
        IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders,
    }
};
idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
```

Then I configure my IdentityProviders, my IdentityProvider uses the Token from the parameter specified in the **Clients Startup.cs**
This works fine for a short token, everything is called as it should be.

**But** if the token is to long it doesn't even get that far. My guess is that the root of the problem lies in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler`

### EDIT 2

### Why the limit is hit so fast:

Apparently my token is added twice to the request to the IdentityServer.

Because of this reason the limit for the cookie is reached pretty fast.

**Clients Startup.cs:**

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
{
    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
    {
        var token = n.Request.Query.Get("token");
        if (token != null)
        {
            n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("token", token);
            n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "idp:CustomIdP";
        }

    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Here I take the **token** from the QueryString. But what I missed here is, 
the `n.ProtocolMessage` contains already the `RequestUri` as State parameter which contains the **token**. 
So the token is sent twice to the IdentityServer. If I remove the token from the `state`-Parameter (which is the right thing to do, as I don't need it on redirecting back) and add it as `AcrValue` it does send it to the IdentityServer as expected.

But still the question remains.

### What if the Token is really long?

Comment: Have you tried looking at it through Fiddler or F12 tools to physically look at the cookie that is being set and then sent back to the server?  How long is it?

Comment: @KyleB the length of the signin-message-cookie is 1024 if the code I want to send is too long, otherwise its shorter

Answer (score 3):

I can't be sure, but, this sounds like it may be a max cookie size problem.
Cookies can only store 4096 bytes in [most browsers](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/), and if cookies are stored in UTF-32 for example, then 1024 characters would [take up all of that space](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and your cookie would be truncated.

You may want to try overriding one of the [CookieOptions](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/CookieOptions.cs) properties in the [AuthenticationOptions](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/AuthenticationOptions.cs).

In the `CookieOptions` class you can provide an [IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider.cs).  According to the comment on the property it may be the solution you are looking for, at the very least you may be able to debug what is going wrong.

```
/// <summary>
///   An optional container in which to store the identity across requests.
///   When used, only a session identifier is sent
///     to the client. This can be used to mitigate potential problems 
///     with very large identities.
/// </summary>
public IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider SessionStoreProvider { get; set; }
```

There is no default implementation for IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider but you can look at how it is used inside [AuthenticationSessionStoreWrapper](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/93bc6bc9b536146b9e3fa0bed21d77283d07f788/source/Core/Configuration/AuthenticationSessionStoreWrapper.cs)

It is wrapped up inside an `AuthenticationSessionStoreWrapper` if you add a provider:

```
static IAuthenticationSessionStore GetSessionStore(IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider provider)
{
    return provider != null ? new AuthenticationSessionStoreWrapper(provider) : null;
}
```

Comment: @FlorianK, I can't find any implementations on the internet, there are some issues on IdentityServer3's github site that mention people both have minor issues and saying that `IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider` works great for them.  I added an edit in my answer to help a bit more.

Comment: I am now implementing my own `IAuthenticationSessionStoreProvider` using Entityframework. Thank you. It is kind of weird that there doesnt exist any EntityFramework implementation.
This feature is also not documented in the official documentation.

Comment: It is kinda weird, I would expect it to be buggy because it is so undocumented.  I don't think it's implemented in IdentityServer4

Comment: It seems that this doesn't solve my problem. This does not affect the (external) sign in message cookie. First of all I don't know if it does solve the problem for the sign-in-message cookie at all (actually I can't really verify this as that is not the problem). But also when looking at the code, this sessionstore is only used for primary sign ins, but not for **external-sign in's**. But my problem occurs for external logins

Comment: can you show us the startup.cs (the authentication portion).  Specifically I am looking for `app.ConfigureAuthentication(..)`, or `app.ConfigureCookieAuthentication`, or where you put the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`

Comment: I updated my question with a few more informations about my structure